# RenderBox was not laid out flutter listview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

The `ListView` is not working. I want to display 3 different stateful widgets to a inside list view but I am getting error

> Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#01b62 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        //wrap with list of widget
        ListView(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Body(box.get('state'), true)),
            Divider(color: Colors.black),
            Expanded(child: Body(box.get('state'), false)),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
```

I am using this code to display widgets inside `ListView`.
my `Body` widget return `listview.builder` or sometimes simple text widget.

When I not using only column widget screen splits in two part - upper `listview.builder` and `lower listview.builder`
and when I am using this code it throwing an error.
Desired output-
first body widget should be display in entire screen and  once first widget end second body widget should be display in entire screen.
How to do this? And why does this error occur?
Note: `shrinkwrap` is `true` inside `Body` widget(`listview.builder`).

Comment: If you use Column with in scrollview like ListView, try to set Column mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min and use Flexible with flex property instead Expand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code

physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

in the all ListView.builder,